# SQL Statement to INSERT into one table from two (using id from another w/no join criteria)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `data_item_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data_source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_AFA125D21A935C57` (`data_source_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_AFA125D21A935C57` FOREIGN KEY (`data_source_id`) REFERENCES `data_sources` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7192 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `map_locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message_codes` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_B28E0DE7BF396750` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `data_items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm trying to accomplish a two-step process. The first query works fine:

```
INSERT INTO data_items (`data`, created, updated, data_item_type, data_source_id) SELECT data_items.data, now(), now(), data_items.data_item_type, 2
    FROM data_items
    WHERE data_items.data_source_id = 1
```

--> 1 and 2 are example values

Now, I want to take every id from 'data_items' (the auto-incs that just got created) and use those id's when inserting each new (corresponding row) in the 'map_locations' table.

So,

```
data_items
id | data_source_id
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 2

map_locations
id | content
1 | aaa
2 | bbb
.... 
3 | aaa
4 | bbb
```

I need to copy row (1, 2), use the id from data_items (3,4) and insert those rows.

Hope this makes sense..it's rather confusing. 
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need the newly created `data_items` to reference their original counterparts; the easiest way to do this would be to modify the schema so that the table includes a self-referencing foreign key:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE data_items
     ADD COLUMN underlying_id INT(11) NULL,
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (underlying_id) REFERENCES data_items (id)
   ```
2. The insertion into `data_items` then becomes:

   ```
   INSERT INTO data_items
     (underlying_id, data, created, updated, data_item_type, data_source_id)
   SELECT id, data, NOW(), NOW(), data_item_type, 2
   FROM   data_items
   WHERE  data_source_id = 1
   ```
3. One can now perform a self-join to obtain the newly created `id`s:

   ```
   INSERT INTO map_locations
     (id, content)
   SELECT new.id, map_locations.content
   FROM   map_locations
     JOIN data_items old USING (id)
     JOIN data_items new ON new.underlying_id = old.id
   WHERE  old.data_source_id = 1
   ```

   Ensure that you perform this query within the same transaction as the previous insertion, using the (default) `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level, to ensure that any concurrent changes to the `data_items` table don't lead to inconsistent state.
4. Again, within the same transaction, clear the `underlying_id` reference:

   ```
   UPDATE data_items SET underlying_id = NULL
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer - I mostly understand this. I started work on another task, but I'll visit this again shortly and attempt to implement this fix. Thank you - I'll report back.

Comment: +100 to you! This worked - what a cool solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand the last line ... why do we clear the "underlying_id". I know what happens if we don't, we get a FKC error.

Comment: @Mr-sk: I'm surprised by that... presumably you then move on to delete the original records, in which case the error is arising because those records are still referenced.  The actual reason for clearing the `underlying_id` was to avoid the links remaining in place during future invocations of step #3, which could cause superfluous records to be included.

Comment: I don't delete the original records, but the error is that the underlying_id has the value of the first time it gets populated, and if I try to copy the same data (with a different source_id) it conflicts. That makes sense, though I'm probably not describing it. I think I understand though, heh. THanks.